# Docker-compose with Golang and Postgres connection is refused

Tags: postgresql, docker, go, docker-compose

I am trying to make the connection with PostgreSQL using Docker Compose. I have a Golang CLI application called flow and it creates, views, adjust's, gets, and removes the budget information.

When I write the docker `docker-compose up -d`, it creates two images and one container.

**Images are**

1. flow-budget_planner
2. postgres

**Container is**

1. PostgresContainer

**Command execution**

- When I run this command, `docker exec -it <Container-ID> psql -U posgresql`, it put in the PostgreSQL terminal to handle the database.
- When I run the postgres, `docker run -it -e POSTGRES_PASSWORD=password postgres`, it gives me the message that `database system is ready to accept connections`.
- When I run the flow-budget_planner in another tab while the Postgres image is running, I get the connection refused message. Here is the command: `docker run -it flow-budget_planner ./flow budget create -c category -a 300`

What should I do to make the connection established and enter the data in PostgreSQL successfully using Docker? Please tell me if you need more info.

Here is the folder structure of it:

```
├── CODE_OF_CONDUCT.md
├── CONTRIBUTING.md
├── Dockerfile
├── LICENSE
├── README.md
├── cmd
│   ├── budget
│   │   ├── budget.go
│   │   └── handler
│   │       ├── adjust.go
│   │       ├── create.go
│   │       ├── get.go
│   │       ├── remove.go
│   │       └── view.go
│   └── other services
│       └── service.go
├── db
│   └── budget_db
│       ├── connection.go
│       └── migrations
│           └── 001_create_budget_table.sql
├── docker-compose.yml
├── go.mod
├── go.sum
└── internal
    ├── app
    │   └── budget
    │       └── budget.go
    └── middleware
        └── env.go
```

**Here is the PostgreSQL connection code**

```
type Variables struct {
    Host     string
    Port     string
    User     string
    Password string
    DBName   string
    SSLMode  string
}

func Connection() (*sql.DB, error) {
    v := Variables{
        Host:     middleware.LoadEnvVariable("host"),
        Port:     middleware.LoadEnvVariable("port"),
        User:     middleware.LoadEnvVariable("user"),
        Password: middleware.LoadEnvVariable("password"),
        DBName:   middleware.LoadEnvVariable("dbname"),
        SSLMode:  middleware.LoadEnvVariable("sslmode"),
    }

    connectionString := fmt.Sprintf("host=%s port=%s user=%s password=%s dbname=%s sslmode=%s", v.Host, v.Port, v.User, v.Password, v.DBName, v.SSLMode)
    db, err := sql.Open("postgres", connectionString)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }

    err = db.Ping()
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }
    return db, nil
}
```

**Here is the Dockerfile**

```
FROM golang:1.22.0-alpine3.19

RUN mkdir -p /app

WORKDIR /app

COPY go.mod /app
COPY go.sum /app

COPY . /app

RUN go mod download

RUN go build -o flow .

CMD ["./flow", "budget"]
```

**Here is the Docker Compose file**

```
version: "3.8"
services:
  postgres:
    image: postgres:latest
    hostname: localhost
    container_name: PostgresContainer
    restart: always
    environment:
      POSTGRES_USER: postgres
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: password
      POSTGRES_DB: flow
    ports:
      - '5432:5432'
    volumes:
      - postgres_data:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    

  budget_planner:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    depends_on:
      - postgres
    environment:
      DATABASE_URL: postgresql://postgres:password@localhost:5432/flow


volumes:
  postgres_data:
    driver: local
```

Comment: I don't understand how you pass and get postgres envs to the application. Is it correct? Because i just see DATABASE_URL, which you are not retrieving on golang code

Comment: @Nux If I am not wrong, you're saying that I should get the DATABASE_URL credentials from the environment variables that I used in the application because I didn't get those credentials from there, I just wrote them manually in the Docker compose file.

Comment: The `DATABASE_URL` from the compose file wouldn't work anyway, because it's not `localhost` but `postgres` as hostname.

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt I changed it but now it is giving me this error: `2024/03/04 07:26:04 dial tcp: lookup postgres on 192.168.65.7:53: read udp 172.17.0.2:51861->192.168.65.7:53: i/o timeout`

Comment: Your DNS server gives you a timeout. Something is VERY wrong.

Comment: @MarkusWMahlberg how to resolve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### 1st problem

Your code seems to refer to these env variables:

```
    v := Variables{
        Host:     middleware.LoadEnvVariable("host"),
        Port:     middleware.LoadEnvVariable("port"),
        User:     middleware.LoadEnvVariable("user"),
        Password: middleware.LoadEnvVariable("password"),
        DBName:   middleware.LoadEnvVariable("dbname"),
        SSLMode:  middleware.LoadEnvVariable("sslmode"),
    }
```

But the only env variable you provide to the application is the connection string `DATABASE_URL`:

```
    environment:
      DATABASE_URL: postgresql://postgres:password@localhost:5432/flow
```

Shouldn't you be using that?

Like this:

```
sql.Open("postgres", middleware.LoadEnvVariable("DATABASE_URL"))
```

Or if that does not work, try manually adding the connection string first:

```
sql.Open("postgres", "postgres://postgres:password@postgres:5432/flow")
```

#### 2nd problem

The connection string itself is wrong: `postgresql://postgres:password@localhost:5432/flow`. `localhost` when used in docker container refers to the localhost of the container itself, not to the localhost of the host machine. Containers started with docker-compose can refer to each other with the service name as the hostname by default.

The driver name might need to be be `postgres` too, not `postgresql`, though it might be interchangeable.

This url should work anyway:

```
postgres://postgres:password@postgres:5432/flow
```

*Edit:* Both `postgres` and `postgresql` work, according to [Postgres documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/libpq-connect.html).

Comment: I used this `postgresql://postgres:password@postgres:5432/flow` URL also but got the same error but I didn't understand 1st problem. Can you help me that?

Comment: Did you fix the first problem?

Comment: Updated the answer with solutions to the first problem.

Comment: Let me check it. Should the `hostname: localhost` from the docker compose be removed

Comment: Yes, yes it should. Did not even notice that, it will cause problems.

Comment: Updated my manual answer to actually use the postgres url, accidentally copypasted the localhost in it right after saying it's wrong.

Comment: No problem. I understand and upvoted. It's pulling right now. Once it is done, I will check it.

Comment: @TeemuRisikko After pulling, it is giving me this problem: `2024/03/04 07:26:04 dial tcp: lookup postgres on 192.168.65.7:53: read udp 172.17.0.2:51861->192.168.65.7:53: i/o timeout`

Comment: Seems like a docker problem possibly not related to this one. Restart the docker engine on your machine first. Then make sure your db is up before trying to connect (add a sleep or a healthcheck). Can't help anymore with that.

Comment: @TeemuRisikko Just one question relevant to docker. Will there be two connection strings in the application? One for localhost and another is for docker-compose or should only one be used in the application? I just want to know.

Comment: If you want to have a different one for local and docker compose, use environment variables.